# For inspection on the hot water

Tags: plumbing

I have a two handle sink and I know the hot water cannot be no hotter than 110
I’m being told when it’s a two handle sink the hot water can be at 140 it doesn’t matter because the cold water is there as well
is that correct number one. Or am I correct on saying the hot water by itself no matter even if you are a two hand sink cannot be no hotter than 110

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if you have a temperature adjusting(anti-scalding) valve at the sink?

Then you might adjust the water heater tank to 140.

If no adjusting valve then the water heater tank needs to be adjusted to 110(think 120).

It is to prevent burns when you turn only the hot water on.

EDIT:  Two handle faucets can have an anti-scalding valve built in, but it is a newer thing.  Older homes with two or even single handle faucets might not have anti-scalding valve.  If you turn on the hot water only, you might get burned if the water is set to more than 110/120 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Plumbing codes do not specify the maximum hot water temperature.  125 F is generally thought to be the safest max, but if you are an adventurer, then your max is the dial on your hot water heater.

If you have children or slow moving older adults then 110 might be a safer setting.  But you get to decide. It's your house.

There are fixtures that prevent too-hot water from going through them.  I am assuming this is not your case.

Comment: Some do. Use in old people homes, schools and hospitals is limited to 46 deg C (about 115 F) max for the hot